# Skip receiving messages broadcasted by me over wireless network

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, wireless, openwrt

I have a code which transmits messages (broadcasts) continuously on wireless network and also receives messages continuously. Hence, I have the transmission and receiving happening simultaneously using pthreads. The problem that I am facing is that I want to skip receiving messages sent by me, and only receive the packets/messages sent by others. Is it possible to do this?

Note that this code runs on a wireless modem and not on the laptop. The modem runs using [OpenWrt OS](http://openwrt.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is no way to prevent receipt of your own node's messages.

Your best bet is to continue letting it receive its own packets and then ignore any that have your MAC or IP address.